# Controlling power to a resistive load with AC

Tags: power, ac

I have AC on an input (110V, 15A) and need to control the amount of power going to a purely resistive load.

Thyristor controlled by PWM seems like an option, but are there other/better ways to do this?

Comment: Light dimmers are doing this.

Comment: If you mean kHz range PWM or faster, that doesn't work with SCRs. You could call what dimmers do PWM, but most people don't.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what the resistive load is.

If it's a lamp filament, then a phase shift thyristor/triac solution is suitable, as you probably want to avoid flicker.

If it's a heater, with a much longer time constant, then you can use a 'burst fire' controller, to control average power. That switches a number of complete cycles on and off. The benefit of this is it doesn't generate as much electrical interference as switching in the middle of a cycle would.

Answer (score 0):

TRIAC, or a bidirectional thyristor is a way to do it.

There are two ways of controlling it:

1. [Phase (Angle) Control (PHC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-fired_controllers), which is how dimmers work.
2. [Zero Crossing Mode](http://www.oztekcorp.com/blog/bid/45104/Controlling-Power-with-SCR-Phase-Angle-vs-Zero-Crossing-Mode)